# Reset TextView textSize after auto-resizing and setting text again

Tags: android, textview, autoresize, android-wrap-content

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:lines="1"
      android:maxLines="1"
      app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
      app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="28sp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />
```

Let's say the text size of the `TextView` is set to minimum (20sp) after resizing and setting the text to for example XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Then, I would like to set a new text which is XXX where I expect that the `TextView` restores it's MaxTextSize. However, the behavior is not as expected and the text size stays the same (minimum (20sp)) since the `TextView` cannot determine its auto size width because of `wrap_content`.

Is it possible to invalidate or reset the `TextView` to it's initial state for it to determine what text size should be applied?

**Note**: It is required that the `TextView` should have `wrap_content` as its width and I am aware that the documentation states that `wrap_content` and auto-resizing sometimes results into an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach that came up with me was giving `minHeight` and `minWidth` to the `TextView` so it could calculate it's dimensions properly and as expected.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="46dp"
  android:minWidth="120dp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:lines="1"
  android:maxLines="1"
  app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
  app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="28sp"
  app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
  app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />
```

Nevertheless, the best answer is found here. [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902987/8670666)

Answer (score 1):

For me, width set to `wrap_content` was the problem. I was using `ConstraintLayout`. Setting width to `0dp` fixed it...